# Isolating Dataset group categories with numerical values introduced as string entries

Tags: dataset

I start with the following table:

```
table = {<|"Counter" -> 1, "NAICS" -> "47-1011", "JobAds" -> "518", 
"JobOpenings" -> "2"|>, <|"Counter" -> 2, "NAICS" -> "29-1122", 
"JobAds" -> "582", "JobOpenings" -> "20"|>, <|"Counter" -> 3, 
"NAICS" -> "31-1011", "JobAds" -> "591", 
"JobOpenings" -> "49"|>, <|"Counter" -> 4, "NAICS" -> "37-2012", 
"JobAds" -> "501", "JobOpenings" -> "58"|>, <|"Counter" -> 5, 
"NAICS" -> "53-1031", "JobAds" -> "629", 
"JobOpenings" -> "59"|>, <|"Counter" -> 6, "NAICS" -> "41-3099", 
"JobAds" -> "663", "JobOpenings" -> "66"|>, <|"Counter" -> 7, 
"NAICS" -> "29-1062", "JobAds" -> "1", 
"JobOpenings" -> "68"|>, <|"Counter" -> 8, "NAICS" -> "21-1023", 
"JobAds" -> "473", "JobOpenings" -> "71"|>, <|"Counter" -> 9, 
"NAICS" -> "21-1093", "JobAds" -> "191", 
"JobOpenings" -> "72"|>, <|"Counter" -> 10, "NAICS" -> "41-2031", 
"JobAds" -> "123", "JobOpenings" -> "92"|>, <|"Counter" -> 11, 
"NAICS" -> "39-9021", "JobAds" -> "561", 
"JobOpenings" -> "127"|>, <|"Counter" -> 12, "NAICS" -> "31-9092",
 "JobAds" -> "698", "JobOpenings" -> "136"|>, <|"Counter" -> 13, 
"NAICS" -> "35-2014", "JobAds" -> "633", 
"JobOpenings" -> "138"|>, <|"Counter" -> 14, "NAICS" -> "41-9022",
 "JobAds" -> "185", "JobOpenings" -> "144"|>, <|"Counter" -> 15, 
"NAICS" -> "11-9051", "JobAds" -> "38", 
"JobOpenings" -> "145"|>, <|"Counter" -> 16, "NAICS" -> "11-2022",
 "JobAds" -> "130", "JobOpenings" -> "154"|>, <|"Counter" -> 17, 
"NAICS" -> "53-3033", "JobAds" -> "98", 
"JobOpenings" -> "155"|>, <|"Counter" -> 18, "NAICS" -> "11-9021",
 "JobAds" -> "634", "JobOpenings" -> "20"|>, <|"Counter" -> 19, 
"NAICS" -> "11-2021", "JobAds" -> "520", 
"JobOpenings" -> "164"|>, <|"Counter" -> 20, "NAICS" -> "11-1021",
 "JobAds" -> "19", "JobOpenings" -> "165"|>, <|"Counter" -> 21, 
"NAICS" -> "43-6011", "JobAds" -> "118", 
"JobOpenings" -> "185"|>, <|"Counter" -> 22, "NAICS" -> "41-1012",
 "JobAds" -> "482", "JobOpenings" -> "199"|>, <|"Counter" -> 23, 
"NAICS" -> "49-3021", "JobAds" -> "47", 
"JobOpenings" -> "206"|>, <|"Counter" -> 24, "NAICS" -> "29-1123",
 "JobAds" -> "16", "JobOpenings" -> "211"|>, <|"Counter" -> 25, 
"NAICS" -> "41-2011", "JobAds" -> "256", 
"JobOpenings" -> "237"|>, <|"Counter" -> 26, "NAICS" -> "35-2021",
 "JobAds" -> "488", "JobOpenings" -> "245"|>, <|"Counter" -> 27, 
"NAICS" -> "31-1014", "JobAds" -> "643", 
"JobOpenings" -> "246"|>, <|"Counter" -> 28, "NAICS" -> "53-3041",
 "JobAds" -> "589", "JobOpenings" -> "258"|>, <|"Counter" -> 29, 
"NAICS" -> "43-3071", "JobAds" -> "326", 
"JobOpenings" -> "271"|>, <|"Counter" -> 30, "NAICS" -> "41-4012",
 "JobAds" -> "212", "JobOpenings" -> "92"|>, <|"Counter" -> 31, 
"NAICS" -> "29-1071", "JobAds" -> "539", 
"JobOpenings" -> "277"|>, <|"Counter" -> 32, "NAICS" -> "29-1063",
 "JobAds" -> "260", "JobOpenings" -> "278"|>, <|"Counter" -> 33, 
"NAICS" -> "11-9111", "JobAds" -> "313", 
"JobOpenings" -> "294"|>, <|"Counter" -> 34, "NAICS" -> "29-2071",
 "JobAds" -> "548", "JobOpenings" -> "296"|>, <|"Counter" -> 35, 
"NAICS" -> "41-4011", "JobAds" -> "551", 
"JobOpenings" -> "301"|>, <|"Counter" -> 36, "NAICS" -> "13-2011",
 "JobAds" -> "415", "JobOpenings" -> "327"|>, <|"Counter" -> 37, 
"NAICS" -> "15-1134", "JobAds" -> "236", 
"JobOpenings" -> "334"|>, <|"Counter" -> 38, "NAICS" -> "47-2152",
 "JobAds" -> "412", "JobOpenings" -> "342"|>, <|"Counter" -> 39, 
"NAICS" -> "11-3121", "JobAds" -> "390", 
"JobOpenings" -> "348"|>, <|"Counter" -> 40, "NAICS" -> "51-1011",
 "JobAds" -> "650", "JobOpenings" -> "349"|>, <|"Counter" -> 41, 
"NAICS" -> "39-5012", "JobAds" -> "665", 
"JobOpenings" -> "362"|>, <|"Counter" -> 42, "NAICS" -> "43-4081",
 "JobAds" -> "217", "JobOpenings" -> "112"|>, <|"Counter" -> 43, 
"NAICS" -> "49-9071", "JobAds" -> "356", 
"JobOpenings" -> "363"|>, <|"Counter" -> 44, "NAICS" -> "43-1011",
 "JobAds" -> "543", "JobOpenings" -> "381"|>, <|"Counter" -> 45, 
"NAICS" -> "11-3031", "JobAds" -> "329", 
"JobOpenings" -> "392"|>, <|"Counter" -> 46, "NAICS" -> "43-4171",
 "JobAds" -> "409", "JobOpenings" -> "396"|>, <|"Counter" -> 47, 
"NAICS" -> "49-1011", "JobAds" -> "472", 
"JobOpenings" -> "402"|>, <|"Counter" -> 48, "NAICS" -> "29-1141",
 "JobAds" -> "186", "JobOpenings" -> "112"|>, <|"Counter" -> 49, 
"NAICS" -> "41-3031", "JobAds" -> "546", 
"JobOpenings" -> "418"|>, <|"Counter" -> 50, "NAICS" -> "37-3011",
 "JobAds" -> "514", "JobOpenings" -> "428"|>, <|"Counter" -> 51, 
"NAICS" -> "15-1151", "JobAds" -> "442", 
"JobOpenings" -> "445"|>, <|"Counter" -> 52, "NAICS" -> "29-2034",
 "JobAds" -> "361", "JobOpenings" -> "450"|>, <|"Counter" -> 53, 
"NAICS" -> "35-9031", "JobAds" -> "595", 
"JobOpenings" -> "472"|>, <|"Counter" -> 54, "NAICS" -> "17-2051",
 "JobAds" -> "648", "JobOpenings" -> "481"|>, <|"Counter" -> 55, 
"NAICS" -> "25-2031", "JobAds" -> "529", 
"JobOpenings" -> "505"|>, <|"Counter" -> 56, "NAICS" -> "53-7061",
 "JobAds" -> "357", "JobOpenings" -> "515"|>, <|"Counter" -> 57, 
"NAICS" -> "47-2031", "JobAds" -> "405", 
"JobOpenings" -> "526"|>, <|"Counter" -> 58, "NAICS" -> "47-2111",
 "JobAds" -> "397", "JobOpenings" -> "532"|>, <|"Counter" -> 59, 
"NAICS" -> "47-2061", "JobAds" -> "589", 
"JobOpenings" -> "534"|>, <|"Counter" -> 60, "NAICS" -> "49-9021",
 "JobAds" -> "647", "JobOpenings" -> "539"|>, <|"Counter" -> 61, 
"NAICS" -> "13-2072", "JobAds" -> "370", 
"JobOpenings" -> "542"|>, <|"Counter" -> 62, "NAICS" -> "35-2012",
 "JobAds" -> "512", "JobOpenings" -> "547"|>, <|"Counter" -> 63, 
"NAICS" -> "53-7062", "JobAds" -> "348", 
"JobOpenings" -> "552"|>, <|"Counter" -> 64, "NAICS" -> "25-2011",
 "JobAds" -> "263", "JobOpenings" -> "564"|>, <|"Counter" -> 65, 
"NAICS" -> "29-1067", "JobAds" -> "489", 
"JobOpenings" -> "569"|>, <|"Counter" -> 66, "NAICS" -> "13-2052",
 "JobAds" -> "338", "JobOpenings" -> "587"|>, <|"Counter" -> 67, 
"NAICS" -> "29-2061", "JobAds" -> "414", 
"JobOpenings" -> "590"|>, <|"Counter" -> 68, "NAICS" -> "43-6013",
 "JobAds" -> "562", "JobOpenings" -> "515"|>, <|"Counter" -> 69, 
"NAICS" -> "33-9032", "JobAds" -> "441", 
"JobOpenings" -> "598"|>, <|"Counter" -> 70, "NAICS" -> "43-3031",
 "JobAds" -> "608", "JobOpenings" -> "610"|>, <|"Counter" -> 71, 
"NAICS" -> "25-2021", "JobAds" -> "666", 
"JobOpenings" -> "617"|>, <|"Counter" -> 72, "NAICS" -> "29-2031",
 "JobAds" -> "339", "JobOpenings" -> "619"|>, <|"Counter" -> 73, 
"NAICS" -> "41-9041", "JobAds" -> "551", 
"JobOpenings" -> "628"|>, <|"Counter" -> 74, "NAICS" -> "29-2052",
 "JobAds" -> "285", "JobOpenings" -> "640"|>, <|"Counter" -> 75, 
"NAICS" -> "53-3032", "JobAds" -> "416", 
"JobOpenings" -> "552"|>, <|"Counter" -> 76, "NAICS" -> "37-1011",
 "JobAds" -> "407", "JobOpenings" -> "664"|>, <|"Counter" -> 77, 
"NAICS" -> "43-5081", "JobAds" -> "268", 
"JobOpenings" -> "674"|>, <|"Counter" -> 78, "NAICS" -> "31-9091",
 "JobAds" -> "318", "JobOpenings" -> "679"|>};
```

Evaluate the following to visualize the table:

```
 tableDs = Dataset[table]
```

The following STRING values in the "Job Openings" column, are
repeated (twice); on purpose; to illustrate my issue :

```
 tableDs[#, "JobOpenings"] & /@ {2, 18}
```

gives: {20, 20}.

```
 tableDs[#, "JobOpenings"] & /@ {10, 30}
```

gives: {92, 92}.

```
 tableDs[#, "JobOpenings"] & /@ {42, 48}
```

gives:  {112, 112}.

```
 tableDs[#, "JobOpenings"] & /@ {56, 68}
```

gives: {515, 115}.

```
 tableDs[#, "JobOpenings"] & /@ {63, 75}
```

gives: {552, 552}.

When I do the following evaluation:

```
tableDs[Select[#[[2]] == "20" &]]
```

I expect to get:
{{2, 29 - 1122, 582, 20}, {18, 11 - 9021, 634, 20}}
but, get only the headings : {"Counter", "NAICS", "JobAds", "JobOpenings"}.

Similarly; with:

```
tableDs[Select[#[[2]] == "92" &]]
```

I expect to get: {{10, 41 - 9022, 185, 92}, {30, 41 - 4012, 212, 92}}.

```
tableDs[Select[#[[2]] == "112" &]]
```

I expect to get: {{42, 43 - 4081, 217, 112}, {48, 29 - 1141, 186, 112}}.

```
tableDs[Select[#[[2]] == "515" &]]
```

I expect to get:  {{56, 53 - 7061, 357, 515}, {68, 43 - 6013, 562, 515}}.

```
tableDs[Select[#[[2]] == "552" &]]
```

I expect to get:  {{63, 53 - 7062, 348, 552},  {75, 53 - 3032, 416, 552}}.

How should I modify the later five commands to get what I expect? Thank you!

Comment: This is the sort of result that you get when you use filters in Excel.  With the above table placed in an Excel spreadsheet, I can introduce filters for each of the columns and then filter by Job Openings, and put a check mark on the value that I want to filter by; say 20; 92; 112; 515 and 552.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the key name. More readable and less error prone than using an index.

```
tableDs[Select[#"JobOpenings" == "20" &]]
```

If you want to use an index, the index for JobOpenings is 4

```
tableDs[Select[#[[4]] == "20" &]]
```

Comment: (+1) `tableDs[Select[#JobOpenings == "20" &]]` and 
`tableDs[Select[#["JobOpenings" ] == "20" &]]` also work.

Comment: Thank you @Rohit Namjoshi! I tried similar approaches to your first answer that never worked and I really appreciate you showing how to use this approach properly.  Now; I can kick myself for not trying a 4 using your second approach! Shame! Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you @kglr !!